# DocumentsUI replacement on Android

Tags: android, root

I have a problem with the stock file manager on my Redmi Note 10S phone,
that's running miui 13 (Android 12). It's also rooted, beacuse I need root to use services like Automagic, etc. My problem is, that every time an app tries to open the stock file manager to pick something (for eg. the SD card for testing), it crashes immediately.

I tried to reinstall it through adb, and I also tried to find, and replace it with MiXplorer (it was unsuccessful btw, because I didn't find the exact location of the app, where I could delete the apk and replace it with the MiX one. I also tried to create a folder in "/product/priv-app/" but I failed, and it says there's not enough storage space (well MiX just said failed, but according to some research I did, that means the partition 's ran out of storage) I don't really know what to do now. Also, I was planning to replace the stock "com.google.android.documentsui" file manager with MiX, but at first I should find it's exact location where I could replace the apk.

If you have any ideas about the possible solutions ( I know, it 'd better to factory reset it, but I don't really want to do that at all), please let me know.

*I've found no solution for that, so I reflashed the phone.*

Yours sincererly,
Gurtnyi